# Sound output doesn't change automatically after connecting to Bluetooth headset

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth, headset

The Bluetooth headset problems in Ubuntu are various and mostly not solved profoundly. This time on 18.04 i get a very fast connection with the headset as soon as I turn it on, but the output device does not change automatically to the connected device. Is there any config file which i could change for this purpose??

PS: In another user account on the same PC, I had to restart the bluetooth service everytime i needed to reconnect my device which stayed unsolved until i erased the account and made a fresh one

Comment: Same problem here, this worked in 16.04. Let us know if you solved it.

Comment: I started to have same problem after following https://github.com/alexa-pi/AlexaPi/wiki/Audio-setup-&-debugging#PulseAudio and then later trying to remove AlexaPi on my laptop.
Although in my case, it was solved by going in settings and choosing the correct sound output device.
Anyways I'd like to know the solution too once you get it right

Comment: @sola I have provided solution for this problem.I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04, and I solved it by just copying the file **default.pa** from **/etc/pulse/** into **/home/username/.config/pulse/** and it's working.

And now everytime you connect or disconnect the sound output will be changed automatically.

```
cp /etc/pulse/default.pa /home/username/.config/pulse/
```

Comment: this doesn't work in Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

Look for pulse audio volume control in Ubuntu software center. One of them (unfortunately has the same "plated" button icon) has a way to choose how the audio will be consumed and even allow to be send to multiple outputs at the same time. Once installed, open it and if the audio is streamed out through your speakers, you can choose your bluetooth output (once the bluetooth output is conected and paired of course). I know is not the best way, but at least you don't need to do all the dance you have to do to make it work.

Comment: Thanks @george. I'm actually looking for the hardcore solution, not such an extra tool. There must be a config file in linux which determines what should happen after a bt audio device connected. These tools should change sth there indeed. I don't know why it "randomly" works and the other time doesn't…