# Sound Not Updating On Output Device Change for Certain Apps

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 and currently the sound works...mostly. There's been one annoying issue I've run into, however: whenever I change the device that the sound outputs from, certain apps don't figure out that I changed the output device. Certain apps, on the other hand, do. Here's a list of which apps I know about:

DOES CHANGE: Google Chrome
DOES NOT CHANGE: Minecraft, Dolphin, Zoom

I figure that this may be an app specific issue and that I may be stuck, but I'd figure that given the scope of the problem, there might be some fix to this problem.

EDIT: In response to the thread [Sound output doesn't change automatically after connecting to Bluetooth headset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086060/sound-output-doesnt-change-automatically-after-connecting-to-bluetooth-headset), I can switch output devices easily but the issue is that I need to restart certain apps to make their sound work. Still a neat trick.

Comment: have a look at this ----> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086060/sound-output-doesnt-change-automatically-after-connecting-to-bluetooth-headset/1159634#1159634

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sound output doesn't change automatically after connecting to Bluetooth headset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086060/sound-output-doesnt-change-automatically-after-connecting-to-bluetooth-headset)