# Audio output doesn't switch when headphones connect or disconnect

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones, ubuntu-mate

[image: Sound Preferences]I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

When I log in to Ubuntu, the audio output is set to whatever is in when I log in, and will not change whether or not I put in the headphones.

If I login with the headphones in, and pull the headphones out, there is no switch to speakers.  Similarly, if I login with the headphones out, plugging in the headphones does nothing.

I can switch the audio output in sound preferences, but I would like the change to occur automatically.

A solution presented here [Sound output doesn't change automatically after connecting to Bluetooth headset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086060/sound-output-doesnt-change-automatically-after-connecting-to-bluetooth-headset) doesn't work.

How can I get the audio output to automatically switch when headphones are pulled out or in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am 99% sure that the solution is to remove `gnome-audio` by running:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-audio
```

I say 99% because I had also removed `callaudiod` (using `sudo apt remove callaudiod`), but it's most likely that removing `gnome-audio` fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi`
to the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file worked for me.

- Reference: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2365869&sid=003638d82209ef2255686d006cf38ee1#p2365869